# What's the meaning of the compile options /DPROFILE and /UPROFILE in Microsoft Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, compiler-options

There is the legacy native c++ project. In the Command Line Property Pages, the /DPROFILE is added as the additional option. I want to remove it. But I don't know if it is safe. I searched the everywhere. Unfortunately I didn't find the explanation regarding /DPROFILE and /UPROFILE. Does anybody the MSDN know page regarding them? And what are they used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/DPROFILE` defines a macro called `PROFILE` with an empty expansion. `/UPROFILE` "undefs" a macro called `PROFILE`. I don't believe that `PROFILE` has any special meaning for the Visual Studio toolchain.

Answer (score 1):

[/D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) defines a preprocessing symbol. `/DPROFILE` means: "define a symbol named `PROFILE`". You'll have to search through your source code for `PROFILE` to see if it's safe without it.

Conversely, the `/UPROFILE` means "undefine `PROFILE`" (see [/U](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3h46dfd.aspx)).